# Exclude a part of WHERE clause from query inside UDF

Tags: sql-server-2008, full-text-search, user-defined-functions

I need to perform a full-text search for substrings in 1 to 3 fields in a SQL Server 2008 R2 database. Only the fields that have non-empty search terms must be searched. I use Entity Framework and the search is a part of a larger LINQ query, so it must be done in a table-valued function to be composable. Therefore, no dynamic SQL possible. So far I have come up with the following UDF:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[SearchPublications] 
(
@version int,
@comment nvarchar(4000),
@description nvarchar(4000),
@tags nvarchar(4000)
)
RETURNS 
@Table_Var TABLE 
(
[ID] [int] NOT NULL,
[IDPublicationType] [int] NOT NULL,
[IDCover] [int] NULL,
[IDSmallCover] [int] NULL,
[IDContent] [int] NOT NULL,
[Cost] [decimal](10, 2) NOT NULL,
[Language] [smallint] NOT NULL,
[Flags] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
[Year] [smallint] NOT NULL,
[Guid] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
[Key] [nvarchar](25) NOT NULL,
[CTime] [datetime] NOT NULL
)
AS
BEGIN
declare @commentParam nvarchar(4000), @descriptionParam nvarchar(4000), @tagsParam nvarchar(4000), @guid nvarchar(32) = 'E442FB8EA8624E289BD13753480AFA8B'
select @commentParam = isnull('"' + @comment + '*"', @guid)
select @descriptionParam = isnull('"' + @description + '*"', @guid)
select @tagsParam = isnull('"' + @tags + '*"', @guid)

insert @Table_Var
select *
from Publications
where (@commentParam = @guid or exists (select
1 from PublicationFields
where IDPublication = Publications.ID and IDField = 3 and IDVersion = @version and
contains(LongValue, @commentParam)
))
and (@descriptionParam = @guid or exists (select
1 from PublicationFields
where IDPublication = Publications.ID and IDField = 4 and IDVersion = @version and
contains(LongValue, @descriptionParam)
))
and (@tagsParam = @guid or exists (select
1 from PublicationFields
where IDPublication = Publications.ID and IDField = 5 and IDVersion = @version and
contains(LongValue, @tagsParam))
)
RETURN 
END
```

However, the use of `@param = @guid or...` construct to exclude empty parameters from search leads to highly suboptimal query plans and searches taking up to 10 seconds to complete. The same searches done without the said construct return almost instantly, but in that case I cannot use a variable number of search terms. Is there a more optimal way to exclude a part of WHERE clause from a query when dynamic SQL is not possible? Writing a separate TVF for each combination of the 3 search parameters is something I would like to avoid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question: the solution was to write a function that searches just for one specified field

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[SearchPublications]
(   
    @version int,
    @field int,
    @search nvarchar(4000)
)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN 
(
    select Publications.*
    from Publications, PublicationFields
    where IDPublication = Publications.ID and IDField = @field and IDVersion = @version and
    contains(LongValue, @search)
)
```

and then combine as many calls to it as needed in the LINQ query using the Intersect method:

```
if (query == null)
{
     query = provider.SearchPublications(search.IDVersion, id, string.Format("\"{0}*\"", value));
}
else
{
     query = query.Intersect(provider.SearchPublications(search.IDVersion, id, string.Format("\"{0}*\"", value)));
}
```